# Specflow Given When Then BUT?

Tags: syntax, cucumber, specflow, gherkin, scenarios

I have been using SpecFlow for a while, without making use of the "but" logic.

Considering the following scenario:

```
Scenario: Kiran logs into the system but doesn't click remember me
Given I have a username of 'Kiran'
And a password of 'password'
When I chose login
But I don't chose remember me
Then I should be logged in
And Taken to the home screen
But My username should not be remembered
```

Couldn't the "but" steps just be interchanged with "and"?

Is there any advantage to using "but"?

Am I right in thinking that this is purely for readability purposes?

I look forward to hearing your thoughts on this.

Many thanks,
Kiran

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes you are right, "and"  and "but" are inter-changeable in the gherkin syntax.

However in my experience "and" is used when you are indicating that a user *should* carry out an action, whereas "but" is best suited to when you want to highlight that a user *should not* perform an action; this is because "but" in the English language is generally used in a negative context.

Hence in your example:

> But I don't chose remember me

Is a good use of "but" as they are not performing an action. Additionally using "but" makes the intent of the test explicit and removes any possible ambiguities.

Comment: Thank you Ben! I have been pondering this all evening.

Comment: No problems :D it is a good question and it helps me solidify my understanding when answering such a question.

Comment: I think it is good to have a syntax to say `Do this` and `Do NOT do that`. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @PrimeByDesign As it's nearly been a year(!) are you going to mark this as answered?

Comment: @BenSmith No but now I think it's time to mark it as answered! Haha sorry I missed your comment back in May.